# How can I convert this function from jquery to pure javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have tried a lot of permutation, I am too dependent on jquery and for this particular assignment I have to do without...

I am now stuck and cannot convert this to work with pure javascript:

```js
   $.root_ = $('body');
   $.root_.on('click', '[data-action="toggle"]', function(e) {
     var $this = $(this),
       element = $(this).attr("data-target") || 'body';
     $(element).toggleClass($(this).attr("data-class"));
     //clear memory reference
     $this = null;
     element = null;

     //save settings
     //saveSettings();

   });
```

```css
.red-bg {
  background: #3d1c24;
}
.white-bg {
  background: #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>

<head></head>

<body>

  <a href="#" data-action="toggle" data-class="red-bg">Change BG (RED)</a><br>
  <a href="#" data-action="toggle" data-class="white-bg">Change BG (WHITE)</a>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Have you tried anything ? What did not work ?

Comment: Not what you're asking, but note that there is no need to assign those variables to `null`.

Comment: okay, I am trying to find out how to do this function 

$.root_.on('click', '[data-action="toggle"]', function(e) {

in pure javascript, I don't know how to do this part...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
document.body.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    var target = e.target;          // convenience
    var dataset = target.dataset;   // convenience
    var selector, element;
    if (dataset.action == 'toggle') {
        selector = dataset.target || 'body';
        element = document.querySelector(selector);
        if (element) {
            element.classList.toggle(dataset['class']);
        }
    }
    //save settings
    //saveSettings();
});
```

> NOTE this uses `node.classList` and `node.querySelector` which probably doesn't work on old IE (older than 11 - don't know, do some research) - but you can get workarounds for for such old tech

NOTE: If the element targeted by the dataset.target can result in multiple elements - do this instead

```
document.body.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    var target = e.target;          // convenience
    if (target.dataset.action != 'toggle' && target.parentNode.dataset.action == 'toggle') {
        target = target.parentNode;
    }
    var dataset = target.dataset;   // convenience
    var selector, elements;
    if (dataset.action == 'toggle') {
        selector = dataset.target || 'body';
        elements = document.querySelectorAll(selector);
        if (elements.length) {
            [].forEach.call(elements, function(element) {
                element.classList.toggle(dataset['class']);
            });
        }
    }
    //save settings
    //saveSettings();
});
```

Comment: Thank you this is just what I needed!

Comment: I've made an amendment to be more accurate to the way jQuery "works"

Comment: I was just about to post and saw your edit! Thanks again for this quick solution! :)

Comment: I have another issue though, when I have child element, something like this (I am using the fontawesome icon):

<a href="#" data-action="toggle" data-class="display-settings">                    <i class="fa fa-gear"> </i>
</a>

Clicking on the <i> child element will not trigger the click, did I do something wrong?

Comment: I'll take the second, but I'd be careful about the first :p

Answer (score -1):

document.querySelector('[data-action="toggle"]').onclick = function() {}

and functions like getElementsByClassName and hasClass addClass

Comment: `hasClass` `addClass` - these do not exist

Comment: Whats the efficient way to write var $this = $(this) in pure javascript; I do not wish to constantly loop through the selectors in the DOM with each click.